# Meteor template state vs. global session

Tags: templates, state, meteor

I'm just started with meteor coming from the Apache-Wicket reusable component focused webapp development.

As a understand if data used in a template is not a mongodb-document the session must be used to store state information e.g. drop-down selection. But the session is global, and if a template is used twice or multiple times, then a fixed session-property 'mySelection' wont work, since all template instances would share/override the same session value. 
The Apache Wicket solution is to use the fullqualified template-path to prefix the property and maintain a unique session property for every template instance.

Is there a general build-in-solution to maintain a "Template-Instance-State" in meteor?
If not, maybe the template-instance itself is accessible somehow from the template functions?

Answer (score 1):

The way I would do this is similar to what you describe as Apache Wicket's solution, except I would write my own code to manage it. So for example, manage Session objects with keys that match each template:

```
function setTemplateSession(key, value) {
  Session.set("template_" + key, value);
}
function getTemplateSession(key) {
  Session.get("template_" + key);
}
```

In your template methods:

```
Template.myList.selection = function() {
  return getTemplateSession("myList");
}

Template.myOtherList.selection = function() {
  return getTemplateSession("myOtherList");
}
```

You could obviously abstract this even further. While it would be nice if Meteor provided this kind of behaviour by default, perhaps instead of looking to Meteor to do that, you could write a smart package that contributes Apache Wicket's philosophy to Meteor's template system?

Answer (score -1):

The template instance itself is accessible via *this*.

See [Templates Instances](http://docs.meteor.com/#template_inst).

Comment: But only in created, rendered, destroyed. Ist there a way to access it in other template functions? Template.abc.data = function(){ return this.mydata}.